# Get list of Facebook applications installed and permissions?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've looked through all the documentation in the FB Graph API and can't find exactly what I'm looking for, so it might not exist, but hoping someone has some ideas.

I'm looking to get a user permission to see all the Facebook applications they have installed and (if possible) what permissions they've given these apps especially as it relates to posting on your Wall.

The idea would be that you would grant my app permission to view all the apps installed and see which ones can post on your behalf (including visibility), so the user would be aware of potentially spammy apps they have installed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API to tell you if a user has an app (other than your own) installed, nor can you see what permissions have been granted to an app (again, other than your own)

Facebook provides the functionality you're trying to implement in its own interface too,  here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Comment: I thought that was the case, but figured I'd confirm just to be sure. Thanks.